# bash script in loop which counts numbers of files and directories

Tags: linux, bash

I need to write script in loop  which will count the number of files and directories and indicates which grater and by how much. Like etc: there are 10 more files than directories.
I was trying something like that but it just show files and directories and I don't have idea how to indicates which is greater etc. Thanks for any help

```
shopt -s dotglob
count=0
for dir in *; do
  test -d "$dir" || continue
  test . = "$dir" && continue
  test .. = "$dir" && continue
  ((count++))
done
echo $count

for -f in *; do
     "$fname"

done
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive dir walk I used for something a while back. Added counting of dirs and files:

```
#!/bin/sh
# recursive directory walk

loop() {
    for i in *
    do 
        if [ -d "$i" ]
        then
            dir=$((dir+1))
            cd "$i"
            loop
        else
            file=$((file+1))
        fi
    done
    cd ..
}
loop
echo dirs: $dir, files: $file
```

Paste it to a `script.sh`  and run with:

```
$ sh script.sh
dirs: 1, files: 11
```

Answer (score 0):

Use could use [`find`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) to get the number of [files/folders](https://superuser.com/questions/1218163/find-all-directories-that-contain-a-certain-character-and-print-them-out) in a directory. Use `wc -l` to count the number of found paths, which you could use to calculate/show the result;

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Path to search
search="/Users/me/Desktop"

# Get number of files
no_files=$(find "$search" -type f | wc -l )

# Number of folders
no_folders=$(find "$search" -type d | wc -l )

echo "Files: ${no_files}"
echo "Folders: ${no_folders}"

# Caculate dif
diff=$((no_files - $no_folders))

# Check if there are more folders or files
if [ "$diff" -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "There are $diff more files then folders!"
else
    diff=$((diff * -1 ) # Invert negative number to positive (-10 -> 10)
    echo "There are $diff more folders then files!"
fi;
```

> Files: 13
>
> Folders: 2
>
> There are 11 more files then folders!

Comment: Isn't the `diff` in the last echo a negative number?

Comment: @MaanooAk Yep, didn't think about that! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the find command to make things simplier.

The following command will list all the files in the given path:

```
find "path" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f
```

And also using the `-type d` you will get the directories.

Piping find into the `wc -l` will give you the number instead of the actual file and directory names, so:

```
root="${1:-.}"

files=$( find "$root" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l)
dirs=$(  find "$root" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | wc -l)

if [ $files -gt $dirs ]; then
    echo "there are $((files - dirs)) more files"
elif [ $files -lt $dirs ]; then
    echo "there are $((dirs - files)) more dirs"
else
    echo "there are the same"
fi
```

Comment: Im not sure if you want recursion... Just remove the `-maxdepth 1` if you want recursion